# Flutter : run some code after a ListView has built

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, scroll

I would like to run this code after a ListView.builder() has built.

```dart
if(listViewScrollController.hasClients)
     listViewScrollController.jumpTo(
         listViewScrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
      );
```

This would allow the user to directly appear at the bottom of the page of a chat screen.
This needs to be executed after the ListView has built its items because otherwise `listViewScrollController.position.maxScrollExtent` would still be `0` instead of the real value.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a **visible Widget** and show when the **ListView** is already loaded

in the pubspec.yaml file

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  fluttertoast: ^3.1.0
  http: ^0.12.0+2
```

in the main.dart file

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
```

declare the following variables in class _MyHomePageState

```
bool _visible=false;
final List<String> entries = <String>[];
```

create a function to fill the List

```
void toastmsm(msm,stad) {
    Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: msm,
        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
        gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
        backgroundColor: stad,
        textColor: Colors.white,
        fontSize: 16.0
    );
}

Future<String> apiRequest(String url) async {
    var response = await http.get(url);
    return response.body;
}

void getprofil() async{
    //expample.
    entries.clear();
    var enlace="https://www.profilusers.com/list.json";
    var graphql=json.decode(await apiRequest(enlace));
    if(graphql.length==1){
        entries.add(graphql["graphql"]["users"]["url"].toString());
    }
    else{
        toastmsm("no data.", Colors.red);
    }
    setState(() {
      if(graphql.length==1){
        _visible=true;
      }
    });
}
```

Widget build

```
Visibility(
    visible: _visible,
    child: Column(
        children: [
            ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: entries.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                ListBody(
                    children: [
                        Image.network('${entries[index]}'),
                    ],
                ),
            ),
        ],
    ),
),
```